# filename_lookup is no available in RHEL 8 with 4.18, whats the alternate?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Our kernel module has been using filename_lookup API, which is not found in RHEL8 with kernel 4.18 (symbol not found in `/proc/kallsyms`).

What is the alternative API/call I can use in place of `filename_lookup()`?

I noticed `kern_path()` symbol available in `/proc/kallsyms`, it returns `struct path *`, but not `struct nameidata`.

Our code is heavily dependent on the `struct nameidata` and I am not able to find any good way to build `struct nameidata` from `struct path`.

What is the best approach for this situation?

Comment: This might be tricky. What I would do is the following. I would use the accessible (currently exported) `kern_path()` function to find the address of `do_path_lookup()`. That can be done using the kernel's instruction decoder (here I am talking about x86 platform as an example) or a third-party disassembler like `udis86`. Once the address of `do_path_lookup()` is found, then I would simply do the same the function `kern_path()` does. There you would have the full contents of `struct nameidata`.

Comment: Thank you.
That sounds like complex and may break with another kernel update.
And looks like do_path_lookup is not defined and declared in 4.18 kernel sources. I could not find it using https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/ident/do_path_lookup

on 4.18, kern_path() calls filename_lookup().

Is there any way we can create nameidata struct from struct path ??

Comment: Yes, in 4.18 `kern_path()` calls `filename_lookup()` directly, so you can get the address of this function directly using the method I described without going through an intermediary function. I does sound complicated until you do it once or twice, and it definitely may break with another kernel update - very much like your code has gotten broken anyway.

It would be helpful to know what exactly you need or use from `struct nameidata`. Then there might be other options as well, and others may be able to add to this topic.